# angularjs sub directive element selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a nested directive like this.

```
<main>
 <app-header></app-header>
 <app-footer></app-footer>
</main>
```

And `app-footer` directive has a small `div` content about 50px height.

```
<div class="footer"></div
```

So I want to get height of footer in `main` directive link function.

```
angular.module("app").directive("main", [function () {

    return {
        "restrict": "E",
        "transclude": true,
        "template": "<h1>hello</h1><div ng-transclude></div>",
        "link": link
    };

    function link(scope, element) {

        var footerHeight1 = $(".footer").height() || 0;  // returns 0
        var footerHeight2 = element.find('.footer');  // returns prevObject

    }
}]);
```

so I can not get height of footer.

Comment: **Why** do you want the height? **When** do you want the height? The footer is probably filled dynamically, and not yet filled when the link function is fired

Comment: Please show us template.html

Comment: Template content is simple. And I updated the template content.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to calculate the margin/padding/height of main, based on the height of the footer. What you can do for this, is something like this (the footer height might change in time):

```
function link(scope, element) {
    var footer = element.find(".footer");

    scope.$watch(function() {
        return footer.height();
    }, function(value) {
        // do something with main, here you know the height of the footer
        // footerheight = value
    });

}
```